# Visual Basic opens a million command prompts

Tags: vb.net, string, cmd

My Visual Basic opens a million command prompts when I only want one that has all the coding going through it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OnButton.Click
        Dim textbox123 As String = TextBoxName.Text
        Dim Textbox12345 As String = TextBoxPassword.Text
        Process.Start("cmd.exe")
        SendKeys.Send("netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=")
        SendKeys.Send(textbox123)
        SendKeys.Send("passord=")
        SendKeys.Send(Textbox12345)
        SendKeys.Send("~")
        SendKeys.Send("exit")
        SendKeys.Send("~")
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OffButton.Click
        Process.Start("cmd")
        SendKeys.Send("netsh wlan stop hostednetwork")
        SendKeys.Send("~")
        SendKeys.Send("exit")
        SendKeys.Send("~")
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxName.TextChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Code1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Startbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Startbutton.Click
        Dim process As New Process()
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe "
        process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        process.Start("cmd")
        SendKeys.Send("netsh wlan start hostednetwork")
        SendKeys.Send("~")
        SendKeys.Send("exit")
        SendKeys.Send("~")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm trying to make a hotspot app for a friend. Don't say use a bat file or something just help

Oh and i want to make it so you can change the name of the ssid and password then click start so it starts. however as i said it runs a million cmds and for some reason it doenst run as admin despite me trying to get it to. ( you can change the name and password in mine its just that it runs a million cmd's and never in admin)

So is there anything you can suggest doing? sorry im not very good with VB plus ive updated it.

it works sometimes but other times it doesnt.

so i have process.startinfo("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")

However i have an error stating that "property access must assign to the property or use its value.

---

Help I know i have asked this question and know I've updated my code.

```
Public Class Hotspot
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OnButton.Click
    Dim textbox123 As String = TextBoxName.Text
    Dim Textbox12345 As String = TextBoxPassword.Text
    Dim code123 As String = Code1.Text
    Shell("cmd.exe /k cd \temp", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
    SendKeys.Send(code123 & textbox123 & " key=" & Textbox12345)
    SendKeys.Send("~")
End Sub
```

Shell("cmd.exe /k cd \temp", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus) is  supposed to only perform the code in one cmd and not open new ones but surprise surprise it doesn't.

That's one line of 3 codes (one for each button ) for 3 buttons I have which are used to set the hosted network, run the hosted network and stop the hosted network.

Basically my app makes a lan hotspot by reading the text in textboxname as the ssid and textboxpassword as the key.

However when I attempt to run my app ( which works btw) it opens a million different command prompts but I only need one.

Comment: Use a bat file or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your startinfo isn't being used because you are passing a sting to ProcessStart instead of a StartInfo object. So all that RunAs is unused. I don't know VB.NET but I know how to look up documentation.

So it won't do what you want.

Multiple windows is usually because you have a batchfile called cmd starting cmd somewhere. That's because you haven't specified the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have since found that my command windows are requesting admin rights.

This Referance :
[ForMore](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ac95030f-1279-4927-9eb9-cd2d85990571/use-the-runas-command-to-run-cmdexe-as-admin-account-from-vb-doesnt-work?forum=vbgeneral)

Put This code in Button

```
 Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = Nothing
    Dim processStartInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    processStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    processStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    processStartInfo.Verb = "runas"
    processStartInfo.Arguments = ""


    processStartInfo.Arguments = "/k netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode = allow  ssid=MyNetworkID key=12345678 keyUsage=persistent"
    processStartInfo.Arguments = "/k netsh wlan start hostednetwork"


processStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    Try
        process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally

        If Not (process Is Nothing) Then
            process.Dispose()
        End If

    End Try
End Sub
```

change the /k to a /c to hide the cmd prompt window